# Show that ($∀x(Fx → Gx) ∧ ∃x(Hx ∧ Fx)) → ∃x(Hx ∧ Gx)$)

Tags: proof-writing, first-order-logic

Can anyone please help me prove:

$$∀x(F(x) → G(x)) ∧ ∃x(H(x) ∧ F(x)) → ∃x(H(x) ∧ G(x))$$

So far, I've been able to get to here:

1. $(∀x(F(x) → G(x)) ∧ ∃x(H(x) ∧ F(x))) \hspace{10pt}$  (1)
2. $∀x(F(x) → G(x))\hspace{104pt}$                  (1)
3. $∃x(H(x) ∧ F(x))\hspace{107pt}$                  (1)
4. $F(a) → G(a)\hspace{123pt}$                      (2) (universal instantiation)
5. $H(b) ∧ F(b) \hspace{128pt}$                     (3) (existential instantiation)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct till step 3.

In step 4, use existential instantiation to write $H(b) \land F(b)$.

In step 5, use universal instantiation on the same $b$ as in 4 to write $F(b) \implies G(b)$

Now, for the same $b$, you have $F(b) \implies G(b)$ , and $H(b) \land F(b)$.  
Use propositional logic rules like $\land-$elimination, $\implies$-elimination and $\land-$introduction to get $H(b) \land G(b)$.

Then in the (n)th step use $\exists$-introduction to say $\exists x H(x) \land G(x)$, after which (1) and (n) together with 
$\implies$-introduction give us $∀x(Fx → Gx) ∧ ∃x(Hx ∧ Fx)) → ∃x(Hx ∧ Gx)$